# auto generating href manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I am using bootstrap tabbable and it generating this href, 
how can I manually generate same href so I can use to select this anchor?

```
<a href="../../_usercontrols/News/#tab-en" id="ctl00_ctl37_g_64b9e1ac_a392_4ca3_abaf_ac62b45c1307_ctl00_tabEN" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
    English
</a>
```

```js
$("[href='../../_usercontrols/News/#tab-en']")
```

Comment: It seems you are using ASP.NET, give a look into [Control.ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I don't like to mix javascript and c# If I don't have to. thanks anyway :)

Comment: The title is funny :). Auto generating something manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
$("[href*='#tab-en']")
```

Or, you may also target to the id:

```
$('#ctl00_ctl37_g_64b9e1ac_a392_4ca3_abaf_ac62b45c1307_ctl00_tabEN')
```

Comment: Well, I have updated my answer with a link. Check that will be very helpful to you.

Comment: according to your documentation It seems [href$=”#tab-en”] is what I needed

Comment: Yeah, you may use that well.